# Failed to resolve tenant name from SMTP address [FailureCategory=Cafe-HttpProxyException]

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to connect O365 exchange / Exchange Online from powershell, I am using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) as guide.

however after running this powershell command

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

I am getting below error

[image]

This is error message

> New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following
>   error message :
>   [ClientAccessServer=SG2PR01CA0093,BackEndServer=,RequestId=2498a60b-034b-40d1-9e57-3e04fdae8d5f,TimeStamp=4/16/2019
>   9:48:00 AM] [FailureCategory=Cafe-HttpProxyException] Failed to resolve tenant name from SMTP address
>   'anna007@nitin.onmicorosft.com'. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>   At line:1 char:12
>   + $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
>   +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
>      gTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108477,PSSessionOpenFailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was username / password issue, I was copy-pasting the username and password and while copy-pasting it was taking space in password.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a lack of an Exchange subscription